# How to pass a variable to a LaTeX code block?

Tags: latex, org-babel, noweb

I'd like to set a variable to be expanded in several LaTeX code blocks. For the sake of simplicity, there is only one in this case, `foo`. `:header-args :var` is ignored: I presume because LaTeX  does not support interactive evaluation? The best I could come up with is verbose. Is there a workaround, for example by using LuaTeX?

foo.org:

```
#+name: x-val
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var val=1 :exports none
val
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: x-val
: 1

#+name: foo    
#+begin_src latex :noweb yes :tangle foo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = <<x-val()>>
\end{document}
#+end_src
```

foo.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = 1
\end{document}
```

The first and second code blocks are evaluated with `C-c C-c` and `C-u M-x org-babel-tangle`, respectively.

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex :var val=1

#+name: foo
#+begin_src latex :noweb yes :tangle foo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = val
\end{document}
#+end_src
```

And I get this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = val
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

init.el ([in full](https://pastebin.com/WQHdy1he)) contains config.el ([in full](https://pastebin.com/uRBZ4ycw)) contains:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages '(org-babel-load-languages '((latex . t) (python . t))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```org
#+name: foo    
#+begin_src latex :noweb yes :tangle foo.tex :var val=1
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = val
\end{document}
#+end_src
```

and so does this:

```org
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex :var val=1

#+name: foo    
#+begin_src latex :noweb yes :tangle foo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = val
\end{document}
#+end_src
```

You have misspelled the property: there should be no colons before or after its name: `header-args`, not `:header-args` (that's a frequent source of confusion: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70483855/2561714)) or you have added the `PROPERTY` and not activated it by pressing `C-c C-c` on it or closed and reopened the file (another frequent source of confusion).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get `x=val`. Updated the post to reflect it.

Comment: Which doesn't work? The first one or the second one? Or both?

Comment: OK, the property one then: did you hit `C-c C-c` on the `#+PROPERTY` line after adding it to the buffer and before tangling? Or save the file, kill the buffer and reopen the file before tangling?

Comment: The pictures show `C-c C-c` on the `#+PROPERTY`, and I also tried the self contained version. Neither works.

Comment: Both work here. Try starting with `emacs -q` and  as minimal an init file as possible. Maybe some package or some setting  is interfering.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed an Error upon launching Emacs ("Error (usepackage) org/:init:..."), and I made the following change to the config file (1) :

```
$ cat ~/.emacs.d/config.el | grep -n5 'org-babel-do' | tail -n5
226-   'org-babel-load-languages
227-   '((emacs-lisp . t) ;; *the change*
228-     (latex . t)
229-     (python . t)))
230-  )
```

(1) which begs for either of adding, rather than setting, new languages to load, or better yet lazy loading.

And this is satisfactory:

```
$ touch foo.tex; truncate -s 0 foo.tex
$ emacs +1 foo.org --eval "(org-babel-tangle)"
$ cat foo.tex | grep 'x = '
x = 1
```

I'm not certain the above change to the configuration is responsible for the error and that in turn is responsible for the seeming satisfactory resolution of the stated problem, so I'll wait for more evidence before accepting this answer.

[image]

Comment: That's most probably the culprit.

Comment: I actually cannot reproduce the problem: doing `emacs -q -l init.el foobar.org` with `init.el` just containing the `org-babel-do-load-languages` to set `python` and `latex` only, I still can tangle the block or evaluate it and the `val` replacement happens. I think I jumped the gun here.